# Center Alignment of Video Off OnWordpress .css having trouble

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a landing page for my company oneoptics.io for some reason I cannot get the video that is being used in my banner to stay in the center of the screen when maximizing on a widescreen monitor. All of the other elements seem to stay centered but the video hugs the left side of the screen. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the CSS that is currently in use.

```
body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif!important;
}
.main_logo img{
    width: 100%;
}
#header{
    padding: 25px 0;
}
.main_menu{
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.menu_ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu_ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 0 0 90px;
}
.menu_ul li a{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.banner_sec{
<!--    background-image: url('http://www.oneoptics.io/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/100240044-aerial-drone-san-francisco-cit_H264HD1080.mp4'); -->
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.banner_overlay{
    background-color: #00000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.background-video {
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
@media (max-width: 5000px) {
.banner_sec{
    background-image: url('http://www.oneoptics.io/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/100240044-aerial-drone-san-francisco-cit_H264HD1080.mp4'); 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    position: center;
}
}
.banner_txt{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-top: 215px;
    text-align: center;
}
.banner_txt strong{
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: block;
}
.banner_txt strong span{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.banner_txt a{
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 400;
    background: #fff;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    margin-top: 180px;
    padding: 20px 75px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.banner_txt a:hover{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the section of background video and floating text like this -

```
<section class="banner_sec">
    <div class="background-video">
        <video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" poster="http://www.oneoptics.io/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Untitled-1.jpg">
            <source src="http://www.oneoptics.io/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/100240044-aerial-drone-san-francisco-cit_H264HD1080.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="banner_overtext">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="banner_txt">
                    <strong>Curated Connectivity Products For<span> Data Center, CATV &amp; Wireless </span></strong>
                    <a href="mailto:stash@oneoptics.io" class="banner_btn">Learn More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner_overlay"></div>
</section>
```

Then change the css of both section.

```
.banner_sec {
    background-image: url(http://www.oneoptics.io/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/100240044-aerial-drone-san-francisco-cit_H264HD1080.mp4);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.background-video {
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media (max-width: 5000px) {
    .banner_sec {
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```